# Remove special characters when copying from Excel to phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql, excel, phpmyadmin

I am constructing a large number of SQL statements within Excel worksheets. When copying these statements, which look structurally sound in both Excel and if I copy them into Notepad, into my phpmyadmin's SQL interface special characters are being added that are causing my Inserts and/or Update statements to fail.

Below is an example of one of these SQL statements as it appears in Excel (or notepad after copy/paste):

```
INSERT INTO `abc_mytable`.`employeeMain` (`employeeID`, `employeeName`, `empSymbol`, `empURL`,`empType`, `empCategory`) 
VALUES (NULL, 'Joe', 'J14', 'https://www.website.com/joe14','FT', 'MANAGE');
```

When I copy/paste this statement into phpmyadmin and attempt to submit the SQL query to my DB, I receive the following error (notice the special characters).

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'INSERTÂ INTOÂ `abc_mytable`.`employeeMain`Â (`employeeID`,Â `employeeName`,Â `empSym' at line 1

Comment: What I'm looking for is some direction on how to remove these special characters, hopefully at the source (in Excel).  Thanks.

Comment: employeeID is the primary key? It shoud not be null

Comment: What is the error returned by Excel?

Comment: There is no error being returned by Excel.  Please read the post above.  I am just copying and pasting SQL statements from Excel into the SQL window in phpmyadmin, that is all.

Comment: The same error occurs when copying from Notepad?

Comment: I copied from Excel to Notepad++ (and Notepad as well), and then to phpmyadmin, with no luck.  These special characters are not going away, although they are not visible anywhere but within Notepad++ with ANSI encoding activated.

Comment: I don´t know how to help you my friend, sorry. The last thing I would try is to change collation to UTF-8. What is the collation you are using?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is `employeeID` is a primary key with auto increment.

You could try:

```
INSERT INTO abc_mytable.employeeMain
   (employeeName, empSymbol, empURL,empType,empCategory) 
VALUES 
   ('Joe', 'J14', 'https://www.website.com/joe14','FT', 'MANAGE');
```

If it is not this problem, you could try not using character **`**, since it seems to be converted to Â someway. They are only necessary if the field's name contains space, and by removing them you could check if the problem are really them. Please feedback us about this.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that did not solve the issue.  I'm pretty sure some of the spaces in Excel are being copied as that special character for some reason.  As you can see, the special character is also appearing directly after the word 'INSERT' as well, so this does not have anything to do with the SQL syntax itself.

Comment: If you are using VBA to call SQL, you could verify each character using `ASC` function. Find then which char is out of this map (http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Data-Type-Functions/SelectedCharactersfromVBAsCharacterCodeSet.htm)

Comment: I am just copying and pasting SQL statements from Excel into the SQL window in phpmyadmin, that is all.

Answer (score 0):

A few options here, as this was annoying me too.

**1. Visual Basic for Applications (VBA):**

A sub along these lines will remove ALL the "fake space" characters in the active sheet:

```
Sub removeFakeSpaces()
    Dim fakeSpace As String
    fakeSpace = " "
    ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Replace What:=fakeSpace, Replacement:=" "
End Sub
```

This replaces all instances of the "fake whitespace" character with an actual space character.

If this does not work, you may need to copy an existing "fake whitespace" character - see below - into the line:

`fakeSpace = " "`

**2. Use Find/Replace in Excel:**

- In the SQL statement in an Excel cell, copy the first "fake space" character (e.g. between "INSERT" and "INTO")
- Use Find/Replace, pasting the copied "fake space" character into the "Find" box
- In the "Replace" box, simply type " " (an actual space)
- You can then copy from the cell into phpmyadmin

**3. Find/Replace outside of Excel:**

- Copy the SQL statement from Excel into an IDE/text editor.
- Highlight the first "fake space" character (e.g. between "INSERT" and "INTO")
- Copy this character
- Use find/replace to find the copied character and replace with " " (an actual space)
- You can then paste this into phpmyadmin